# Algorithm for heat map?

Tags: algorithm, heatmap

I have a list of values each with latitude and longitude.  I'm looking to create a translucent heatmap image to overlay on Google Maps.  I know there are server side and flash based solutions already, but I want to build this in javascript using the canvas tag.

However, I can't seem to find a concise description of the algorithm used to turn coordinates and values into a heatmap.  Can anyone provide or link to one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The basic idea would be to create a grid and project every lat,lng coord to that grid.  I would use a 2D array of ints.

The psuedo-code would be:

```
for each coord
  cell = coord projected to grid
  increment cell value
end

for 0 to # of passes
  for each row
   for each col
     if grid[row,col] > 0 then
       grid[row,col] += 1
       increment_adjacent_cells(row, col)
     end
   end
  end
end
```

So, the idea is that the higher the int value, the hotter that cell is.  increment_adjacent_cells should increment the values in all 8 adjacent cells.

Comment: This is the basic idea; but instead of doing multiple passes to "spread" the heat, it'd be better to have something like a circular Gaussian mask that you can just add into the grid at every data point.

Also, this question might have useful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117048/creating-heatmaps-using-canvas-element

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to solve this in javascript using the canvas element, here is my current result:

http://gist.github.com/346165

I have to fix the gaussian filter and the color mapping, because it doesn't give good results currently.

Comment: That's an interesting thing. I was planning to draw heatmaps with DOM objects (no blur obviously) but your solution could provide some serverside-alike results in terms of the look and feel. Your problem with colors is caused by the `maximum` variable.

Comment: This looks nice - fast and reusable: http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html

Comment: I saved your code as [a jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/aewmJ/) for folks to try out. It's an interesting approach but doesn't seem to render a sensible result. Did I miss something? Maybe browsers have changed since you authored this code.

Answer (score 2):

A faster way of building a heatmap could be to use a queue:

Pseudocode:

```
Add an element to queue (first in heatmap(x,y, val))
While (!queue.isEmpty())
{
    elem = queue.pop()
    queue.push(elem.x + 1, elem.y, val-1)
    queue.push(elem.x - 1, elem.y, val-1)
    queue.push(elem.x, elem.y + 1, val-1)
    queue.push(elem.x, elem.y - 1, val-1)
}
```

This saves on tons of iterations!

Comment: Would this ever finish, every pop, 4 more pushes to the queue, so it would never be empty (or am I being dumb!) ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this project if you are looking for something that looks more like 'tv weather maps':

https://github.com/optimisme/javascript-temperatureMap

Comment: Please add some content from the link.