# How to get color values between a given color and white?

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors, percentage

I need to recover all the values bewteen a given color and white. For example, from this blue (#4A90E2) until plain white (#ffffff), and get values dependeing on a certain number of elements.

If I have 6 elements, I would need 6 colors being those a percentage representing the 6 elements I have, every single one a bit lighter than the previous one as if you divide the spectrum between the two first colors in six equal parts.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/17527156/2968762

Comment: Colors are only hexa numbers, so you can convert them to dec number, calculate the difference between the 2 numbers, divide by X (you will get the gap you need to add to get the next color). Then you convert back to hexa to get your color

Answer (score 0):

[RGB to hex and hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

In this post, the answer shows functions to transform RGB to hex and back. Using these functions, one can get the difference.

Let's assume we have #007FFF, if we want to divide this into 2 steps, first we get the numerical values:
R: 0, G: 127, Blue: 255
now we get the difference from white( 255):
255-0 = 0, 255- 127=128, 255-255=0

These numbers can now be divided by however many steps you want.
Using 2 steps this would be: 127.5, 64, 0

Now one can iterate over the base numbers we transformed to RGB, and add the step value every iteration for a smooth step.

```js
function getColorSteps(color,steps) {
   var rgb=hexToRgb(color);
   var deltaRgb = { r: 255-(rgb.r/steps), g: 255-(rgb.g/steps), b:255-(rgb.b/steps) };
   colors = [];
   for (var i = 1; i <= steps; i++) {       
       colors.push({r:rgb.r+deltaRgb.r*i,g:rgb.g+deltaRgb.g*i,b:rgb.b+deltaRgb.b*i});
   }
   return colors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function works out for you:

```
function getColors(color, n) {
    // i'm supposing your color is a string in format '#XXXXXX'
    const white = 0xFF;
    const redComponent = parseInt("0x" + color[1] + color[2]);
    const greenComponent = parseInt("0x" + color[3] + color[4]);
    const blueComponent = parseInt("0x" + color[5] + color[6]);

    var colors = [];
    for(var i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        var red = white - (i*(white-redComponent))/(n+1) + 0xf00;
        var green = white - (i*(white-greenComponent))/(n+1) + 0xf00;
        var blue = white - (i*(white-blueComponent))/(n+1) + 0xf00;

        colors.push("#" + red.toString(16).substr(1,2) + green.toString(16).substr(1,2) + blue.toString(16).substr(1,2));
    }
    return colors;            
}
```