# Which javascript or JQuery charting tool can I use to create heatmap charts with vertical column labels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, heatmap

I'm looking for a charting library that can draw heatmap charts, and has the option of displaying column label text vertically (allowing me to fit lots of columns on the screen regardless of the length of the labels)

Ideally the library would be free for a charity/educational organisation.

Here's an example of a simple heatmap with vertical labels:

[image]

That chart was created using FusionCharts, which is not suitable as it is a flash-based product and is expensive to license.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117048/creating-heatmaps-using-canvas-element

Comment: @AntonJs that question refers to a different kind of heatmap

Comment: You could export the chart to image on the server, and then embed the image on your page. This would eliminate your Flash problem, if not the license amount.

Comment: You could use http://fcimg.org for exporting FusionCharts to images.

Answer (score 0):

You could always roll this yourself. Most of the table can be generated using ordinary HTML, with the exception of the vertical labels at the bottom. You could tackle that with [Rafael](http://raphaeljs.com), a JavaScript library that allows you to draw on an HTML canvas. Drawing rotated text is actually available out of the box so it won't be hard to implement.

Comment: I'm really looking for a ready-made solution so that I don't have to roll my own, but thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is also called a TreeMap (in some circles anyway).
Check out [thejit.org](http://thejit.org)

Under the demos checkout the `treemap` and the `icicle chart`.

Answer (score -2):

At this url you can find what you are looking for [heatmapjs](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/)

Comment: That looks like a different kind of heatmap

Comment: Wrong answer; not relevant.