# Is there any javascript libs for heatmaps which support Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, heatmap, vml

I am looking for some free javascript framework to implement nice heatmap chart. It should look something like [D3 Heatmap](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084). The problem is that it have to work in IE8 which do not support SVG. I googled for other libs, but found nothing suitable. The only thing which seems to work fine is [jQuery Hottie](https://github.com/DLarsen/jquery-hottie), but its feature set is not sufficient, I need something more mature and bigger. Currently I am thinking about making my own solution using VML or plain tables and css.

So, is there any javascript libs for heatmaps which support Internet Explorer 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many heatmap solutions out there.

I recommend you check out the following links:

1. [Heatmap JS](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/): realtime, uses HTML5, moderate customization options
2. [Which javascript or JQuery charting tool can I use to create heatmap charts with vertical column labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720343/which-javascript-or-jquery-charting-tool-can-i-use-to-create-heatmap-charts-with)
3. [Creating heatmaps using <canvas> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117048/creating-heatmaps-using-canvas-element)

Also note that searching on the term `jQuery TreeMap` might yield better results.

Good luck!

Comment: 1. Heatmap JS is not my case, it slightly different. 2. I have tryied the solutions from there, the demos from thejit.org even works in IE8! But they are not covering my use cases. 3. Different kind of hitmap.